# Will MS Visual Studio 2008 show help on my own functions if I use Javadoc style comments for them?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comments, javadoc

For example in C# or in JavaScript documents.
If not, is there point in using [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comments in ASP.NET programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer to that is no, it won't. Why would you use Javadoc style comments rather than the XML comments? The XML comments will be automatically displayed by the Intellisense engine and also allow you to create external docs through tools like SandCastle.

Comment: Agreed - the XML comments are the way to go and give shippable documentation along with your components (via the XML files that get built).

Answer (score 1):

Scott is correct, you should use the native XML comments to get the intellisense you are looking for.  As far as Javascript intellisense, I think you need to create a special .js file (either manually or dynamically) with xml comments for this and then reference it within your .js files.  Most .js libraries include these special .js commented files that you can reference for an example.